# My website has https over login layer only. Can a service worker be implemented for my site to implement chrome notification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, push-notification, service-worker

I want notifications for my website even when any tab of the site is closed. I found service worker to be useful for this. I have read that service workers are serviceable only over https site. On my website https is enabled only for the login functionality but the whole site is over http only. Can a service worker be made in such a case so that I can have chrome notifications. I suppose I will be able to serve any api requests required for service worker over https for my website.

I haven't done any prior work related to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the page that calls `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` and the service worker JavaScript itself needs to be served over HTTPS. Those requirements can't be avoided.

Assuming you meet those two requirements, there's nothing stopping you from using push notifications. There's no way for the service worker or for the push messaging server to know that there are other pages on your site that aren't available via HTTP. Once a user clicks on your notification, it's up to you to determine what action to take via the [`onnotificationclick` callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/onnotificationclick), and I don't believe there's anything stopping you from opening a new window with an HTTP URL as the destination.

That being said, I'd strongly encourage you to migrate your whole site to HTTPS! Your users will benefit from it.